# How to draw data dependency waits when drawing a 5 stage pipeline diagram?

Tags: pipeline, cpu-architecture

How to draw data dependency waits when drawing a 5 stage pipeline diagram? Is my answer correct?

Instructions

```
1. ADD X, Y, Y
2. ADD Z, Y, X
3. SUB V, X, W
4. ADD Z, Z, V
```

Here is the Pipeline diagram

[image: Pipeline diagram]

Is my pipeline diagram correct?

Comment: We need additional information: 1) Is forwarding present? i.e. can the results written in the *WR* stage be read immediately by the *EX* stage? 2) Can the architecture fetch while accessing memory? Harward architectures or architectures with two memory ports can. Finally, is there a reason for the *ID* stage of the third instruction not being able to start on cycle 5? Also, such instruction depends on *X* and *W* that are ready on cycle 7. Tell us your reasoning so we can tell if it's right or wrong, otherwise we are reduced to guessing

Comment: Hello Ms. Bloom, the question has only these information. _Assume we use a pipeline with a 5-stage instruction: IF, ID, EX, MEM and WR. Assume that the pipeline does not use operand forwarding and that the only sources of pipeline stalls are the data hazards. Draw a multi-cycle pipeline diagram to show the execution of the five instructions listed in (a). How long does it take for the instruction sequence to complete?_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the instruction format is `op <dest>, <src1>, <src2>`

We can track the dependency explicitly

```
1. ADD X, Y, Y    Depends on: Y     Produces: X
2. ADD Z, Y, X    Depends on: Y, X  Produces: Z
3. SUB V, X, W    Depends on: X, W  Produces: V
4. ADD Z, Z, V    Depends on: Z, V  Produces: Z
```

Knowing that there is no *operand forwarding*, and instruction *i* can read a result of an instruction *j* only after *j* completes the *WR* stage.

`ADD X, Y, Y` depends on *Y* but no instruction produces it, it is already ready.  Thus it can start executing just after being fetched and decoded.
So it starts on cycle 1 and ends on cycle 5

[image: Pipeline until instruction 1]

`ADD Z, Y, X` is fetched as soon as the fetch unit is free, this happen at cycle 2. It is then decode as soon as the decode unit is free after that, at cycle 3.
It cannot be executed right after, on cycle 4, because it depends on *Y* and *X*, the latter being produced by instruction 1 and thus available only at cycle 6.
**Note** here that the stage that is stalling is not *IF* but *ID*. It is this stage that is prevented from moving data on the next one. Imagine there is a latch between each stage.
*IF* can starts fetching the new instruction on the next cycle but it cannot complete (i.e. must be stalled too) until *ID* is allowed to write its output (otherwise the input of *ID* would change and so would its output).

[image: Pipeline until instruction 2]

`SUB V, X, W` can be fetched at cycle 3 because the fetching of instruction 2 ends at cycle 3 and so the fetch unit is free.
However the fetch unit cannot write the result in the latch between itself and the decode unit because the decode unit is stalled and must keep its current input value (or the decode would change).
So the fetch must be stalled too, until the decode unit writes to its output latch at cycle 6.
The decode can thus start at cycle 6.
The instruction depends on *X* and *W*, the former is available at cycle 6 and the latter since cycle 1; thus the *EX* can starts just after *ID*, i.e. at cycle 7.

[image: Pipeline until instruction 3]

`ADD Z, Z, V` can start being fetched at cycle 6, when the fetch unit had written its result to the latch to the decode unit.
The execution can start only at cycle 10 because this instruction depends on *V* that is produced by instruction 3 at cycle 10.
The dependency on *Z* is not a problem since this data is available at cycle 9.

[image: Pipeline until instruction 4]

Comment: Thank you Ms. Bloom, thank God, I think I have understood it clearly. (Did you see my revised answer which I posted before your answer?). Your answer helped me confirmed that I have indeed learned this properly. Actually I have no teachers and all done by self studying. I am going through the books Stallings, Tanenbaum, Schneider. Bookshear in addition to Youtube and other websites). Biggest problem I have is making sure that I have learnt them properly. Thank you for your support.

Comment: @Trang You are welcome. It seems there are the [solutions of the exercises of Stalling](https://www.pearsonhighered.com/product/Stallings-Solutions-for-Computer-Organization-and-Architecture-8th-Edition/9780136088592.html) online. Not sure what they actually are, though. Maybe that can help you check your answers.